# Is it a bet on price fluctuations and against the house?

Tags: foreign-exchange, online-brokerage, cfd

When one trades Forex, CFDs, metals, or stock indexes with online brokerage firms, does it mean we bet on the price fluctuations without actually owning the underlying assets and is it a bet against the house (against those brokerage firms)?

Comment: Your hypothesis may be true for some but not all of the kinds of instruments you list, and for some but not all of what may be called "online brokerage firms." Care to be more specific? Examples of firms? In what country? etc.

Comment: What is it that you're trading? You can trade bets, you can trade the actual assets...

Comment: @Chris W. Rea : I live in Cambodia, a country in Southeast Asia, bordered with Vietnam and Thailand. Actually, I would like to learn to invest in stocks but the stock market in my country seems to get nowhere with only one firm listed. I want to trade international active stocks but that's not possible in my country because so far there are only several unlicensed online brokerage firms offering forex, gold, and CFDs trading. So I'm just trying to answer a few vital questions before giving it a try.@littleadv

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the specific instrument to which you are referring.

It is possible to make straight bets that are cash-settled and in which the underlying commodity or instrument will never be bought or sold.  It is also possible to have such a contract be settled in the underlying (if the cash value is appropriate, then the cash settlement can be used to purchase the underlying directly, if necessary).  Physical delivery was [predominant until the last few decades](http://www.futuresmag.com/2006/07/25/financial-settlement-vs-physical-delivery).  Most traders, as opposed to hedgers or strategics, are going to prefer cash-settled contracts as opposed to physical delivery.

It is possible to make trades with a brokerage firm such that the firm pays if the trader wins the bet.  The firm will typically find parties on the other side to even out this bet and leave itself neutral as to the outcome (plus a small premium it charges each side for the cost of making the market).  The cost charged to one contracting party should be set by the dealer in relation to prices being charged to parties making the opposite, matching bet (in this way, brokers are following market price, while traders are setting it).

Financially, options and contracts can be settled for cash or for the underlying, and they can be made directly with the opposite bettor or with a neutral dealer.